# validate the location input is valid or not ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, uitextfield

If we want to enter the location as Saidapet in Textfield, it is possible to compare the typed location is valid or not. I want to compare the text with google map. Can anyone tried this. Kindly help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try google maps APIs of autocomplete location address and use that response to check user input location present or not.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you can use "Google Places API" for iOS and then simply check the entered place name in your UITextField either in "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" delegate method or in any button press action.

Comment: Actually, I want to validate the location(UItextfield for example : Saidapet) when it is in Offline mode. After the internet is available, i have to validate the typed location(Saidapet) with google map(For example: Saidapet railway station, chennai, Tamilnadu). How to do this. Pease help me.

Comment: To validate the location in offline mode, you need to create a separate location dictionary. Update that local dictionary every time user connects to the internet. If your app user is limited to some specific region, the local db size will be small, otherwise, it will consume iPhone memory, as you have to save all small big location names locally.